# Error PWC6345 on running deployed JSP application in glassFish

Tags: java, jsp, glassfish

After successfully deploying a Java JSP application to my local glassfish server, I get the following error when trying to run it (either from my IDE - Eclipse, or by entering the URL in a browser):

`org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is required`

The application is just a simple hello world app using JSP, however, this error only occurs if I write it using JSP; an equivalent application using just a simple servlet + printing out html lines works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says it all.

Glassfish has been started using JRE not JDK, which means that `javac` which is needed to compile JSP pages is not available.

In Eclipse configure Glassfish to use JDK not JRE.